# Scanner.nextLine() sending data but won't compare it inside of a function

Tags: java

Trying to take data from scanner and pass it to a function that compares that data to an array, but when I send the data that the scanner receives it won't compare.

Scan class

```java
Key.use(scan.nextLine().toString(), retrievedkey);
```

Key function that iterates through the array to compare the first parameter to the arraylist

```java
public static void use(String door, String[][] key){
        var arraylength = key[1].length;
        for (int i = 0; i<=arraylength;){
            i++;
            if (door == key[1][i]) {
                canOpen = true;
                System.out.println(canOpen);
            }
            else {
                canOpen = false; 
                System.out.println(canOpen + " " + door + " " + Arrays.toString(key[1]));
            }
            return;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

When sending data separately from the scan function the key function works. Ex:

```
Key.use("Front door", retrievedkey)
```

But the scanner prints the input as "door" yet isn't read by the function. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Java uses methods, not functions. Also, that's an array, not ArrayList.

Comment: The following lines also seem wrong:  `var arraylength = key.length; // rows` `for(int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {` `if(door.equals(key[0][i])) { // arrays in Java are zero indexed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if (door == key[1][i]) {
                canOpen = true;
                System.out.println(canOpen);
            }
```

You should use

```
if (door.equals(key[i][1]))
```

instead of

```
if (door == key[1][i])
```

And there is no need to use toString() method in

```
Key.use(scan.nextLine().toString(), retrievedkey);
```

since nextLine() reads String as input.